# Why do I need setTimeout in this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, frontend

```
$(document).on('click', '#JS_btn1', function(e) {
  var self = $(this);
  setTimeout(function(){
    self.parent('div').html('<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn_ok" id="JS_btn2">OK</a>');
  });
})
```

The code shows that #JS_btn1 was replaced by #JS_btn2 before finishing the listener events. Now the question is that why does I need setTimeout in IE7/8 to prevent error?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Who says it needs to to prevent an error? What error?

Comment: Wrapping the code in `setTimeout` with no timeout defined just means: "wait until the currently run code is executed and then run the callback". Maybe that will answer your question.

Comment: The error message is “Unable to get property 'nodeName' of undefined or null reference”

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, IE 7/8 is holding a reference to the DOM node that you are replacing, and then tries to retrieve the nodeName. Since the node is removed in your function, and from the DOM, IE throws the error. Calling setTimeout() allows the caller to release the node before you replace it.